# Json deserializer seems to not work

Tags: c#, json

I did a little code to deserialize json file into an object using Json.Net:

```
private void populate()
    {
        LevelsConfig RootObject = new LevelsConfig();
        string json = File.ReadAllText("jsontest");
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, RootObject);
    }
```

LevelsConfig looks like so:

```
public class LevelsConfig
{
    public List<DefinitionRoot> roots { get; set; }
}
```

There are a bunch of classes below that, each to represent a 'deeper' part of json like:

```
public class DefinitionRoot
{
    public string LevelName { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public int StartingGold { get; set; }
    public int StartingLives { get; set; }
    public List<UndertimePart> UndertimeParts { get; set; }
    public List<Wave> Waves { get; set; }
}

public class Wave
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double TimeBeforeStart { get; set; }
    public int GoldBrave { get; set; }
    public List<SubWave> SubWaves { get; set; }
}
```

and so on.

Hovever, the populate function written at top of this post returns an empty object. Why is that happening?

EDIT: I need to delete json file example since im not sure I should be showing it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deserialize the JSON to an object that has a property that is a collection of `LevelsConfig` with a name of `LevelsConfig`.

```
private void populate()
{
    var obj = new {LevelsConfig = new List<LevelsConfig>() }   
    string json = File.ReadAllText("jsontest");
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, obj);

    foreach (var config in obj.LevelsConfig) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: after correcting some names of clases/fields populate works also. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and not the `JsonConvert.PopulateObject`. The `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` is used to populate an existing object instance with values from JSON.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("jsontest");
var levelsConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LevelsConfig>>(json);
```

Comment: No, `DeserializeObject` creates a new object, `PopulateObject` is used to populate an existing object. No reason to not use `DeserializeObject` here though.

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks. Meant that. Ended up typing the wrong method.